# Can there be only one Distribution Certificate per App Developer?

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate, code-signing

I experience big trouble with the iOS provisioning / certification.

Recently I submitted an app to App Store with a normal App Store Distribution Certificate. And then I wanted to create a AdHoc Beta Test for another app, and I am not sure what happened next but now the Provisioning Portal doesn't list my App Store Distribution Certificate anymore. Instead it only lists my AdHoc BetaTest Certificate.

Also, the Provisioning Portal has no way to create a new Certificate.
Recently I renewed my developer account so maybe everything expired causing the trouble?

My Keychain has an entry "iPhone Distribution: Mikhalo Ivanokov", with green checkmark "This certificate is valid", expiring in Nov 10, 2012.

But Provisioning Portal doesn't list this Distribution Certificate. Only the AdHoc BetaTest certificate.

How can I fix this? Does anyone know what might have happened? Did Xcode replace my App Store Distribution Certificate with my AdHoc Distribution Certificate? Can I have two, or must I somehow delete the AdHoc Distribution Certificate first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you had a distribution certificate and by mistake modified it to an Ad Hoc certificate (it easily can be done in Distribution tab of Provisioning Portal). You just need to make one more distribution certificate and sign your application with it if you want to update it in App Store.

You don't need to delete your Ad Hoc certificate, you just can maintain both distribution and Ad Hoc certificates on your developer Mac. You just need sign your application with right kind of certificate for publishing in App Store and Ad Hoc distribution.

Comment: The problem is I can't add new Distribution Certificate. There is no button for adding new one. Also when I go to distribution tab all I can do is Download or Revoke, or click on my name. But not modify that certificate.

Comment: You don't need certificate - you need new distribution provisioning profile: Provisioning Portal -> Provisioning -> Distribution -> New Profile.

Answer (score 6):

You can only have one distribution and development certificate. However you can have multiple distribution profiles. So in your case, you can use the same distribution certificate to create an adhoc distribution profile and an app store distribution distribution profile. Remember that a profile is created by combining your certificate (either your dev or distribution one), an app id and optionally a list of devices.

Comment: You can have multiple dev certs (there's probably a limit but I haven't heard or hit it at 3 personal + dozens on a team). I'm pretty sure you used to be limited to one distro cert, but evidently Apple changed that because [the limit is now three (3)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38195289/900873). I just made a second, so it's definitely not just 1 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

IOS distribution certificate personal account can only apply for three