# Maximum number of certificate generated issue

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer

[image: Please Check]Hello I want to build IPA so I am creating Development certificate but I am getting message from apple .

**iOS App Development(Maximum number of certificates generated)**

So I do research on that and I realize that only limit of 3 certificate  but when I check on my account than in my account I have only two certificate still I am not able to add one more certificate so I am not able to understand why I am not able to add certificate.

Here I am attaching screen shot so you can understand

[image: Please check[![please check i have only two certificate]

[image]

Comment: Can you check the count of Production certificate ? Refer link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194971/how-many-ios-ad-hoc-distibution-certificates-can-be-created-limit-for-certifica

Comment: You already have two certificates, why you need another one ?

Comment: please check my question i added Screen Shot

Comment: But i want create IPA of different App and those two certificate i for different app

Comment: I am also getting same issue , do you have any solution ?